# Weak normal map bake?

Tags: normals

I have baked my high poly to my low poly , But the end result gives a very weak bump [image]
This image is the low poly

[image]
this image is high poly
is there anyway to get strong bump maps?

Comment: BI or cycles? For BI increase the normal value in the texture settings and tick normal map in sampling. For cycles are you using a bump node or feeding it into the displace?

Comment: BI , but this is for baking, not the material

Comment: yes but after you bake the normal map you need to apply it to the low poly model. The settings adjust the strength of the normal map.

Answer (score 5):

When looking straight at a model, there must be visible curvature on the model for the normal map effect to be visible.

I've illustrated this using several cubes and a 3D Viewport Matcap Normals' surface.  The view is top-down orthographic.

The cube at the top-left is just a default cube with no bevel.  It is invisible to normal mapping.

The top-right cube has only a very small bevel and it is barely visible in contrast to the plane.

The two bottom cubes were beveled enough so that the curvature across the top and side surfaces is clearly visible.

[image]