# Tried Everything, Can't Generate a Correct Normal Map

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have been working on making a normal map where I project it from a high poly to a low poly mesh.  I have tried cages, adjusting margins, adjusting ray distances, basically everything and I'm still stumped.  The best I can get my normal map to come out to is attached below.  What're your guys' thoughts?[image]

Comment: What were you baking from? How does highpoly look like? Does it have faces which are beveled and oriented not at 90 degrees to its flat surface? Margin setting is not something that will have any serious impact, so it can be left on defaults

Comment: Is the low poly and high poly object in the same or almost the same location ? If you change the location then the normal maps are going to be projected in an unwanted way.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been at work.  So if you look in the picture, you can actually see both the low poly and the high poly @MrZak.  The low poly is gray for the material that I had to add (to put the normal map image onto the image texture node) and the high poly is that tan object you see.  The faces aren't beveled and are parallel with the surface.  But beveling can screw things up?  Also, I am baking from the high poly to the low poly mesh

Comment: @Retrax, the two meshes are indeed at the same location, same origin spot, everything is applied, etc.

Comment: Now I see both objects are there in place however this doesn't allow to see geometry of the highpoly. This is important since if highpoly doesn't have some curvature on its corners there won't be any normal map effect - it doesn't catch 90 degree corners. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/weak-normal-map-bake for example. Bevel can make it worse, can make better, depends on geometry mostly, but it isn't the only way to model highpoly

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense.  I added a subdivision surface modifier and it did the trick.  Thanks so much for the help man! @MrZak